# Replace function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem  that replace function does not work

```
DECLARE @Tabela nvarchar(25)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

SET @Tabela = '_#tmp_tt2_POS_racuni_'
SET @query = 'SELECT * INTO '+@Tabela+((replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(),121),'''-''',''''))+'-'+(replace(convert(nvarchar(10),getdate(),108),''':''','''')))+'NP'+' FROM _tabels'

PRINT @query
```

```
SELECT * 
INTO _#tmp_tt2_POS_racuni_2021-12-21-11:15:27NP 
FROM _tabels 

Completion time: 2021-12-21T11:15:27.0724917+01:00
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Show us the @query contents too.

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with this output and what output you're expecting?

Comment: @jarlh This looks like [tag:sql-server], but let's wait for OP to confirm

Comment: What does *does not work* mean? Is there an error? Is the replacement not working like intended?

Comment: SQL-Sever is this yes.

Comment: Problem is or expected result is: _#tmp_tt2_POS_racuni_20211221-111527NP

Comment: @Nejc why are you using such table names in the first place? All supported SQL Server versions and editions allow partitioning - I think even LocalDB

Comment: A table called `_#tmp_tt2_POS_racuni_` isn't going to be *temporary* like it's name implies either. A *temporary* table's name **must** begin with a has (`#`); yours starts with an underscore (`_`). It seems both (read all?) your table (object) names do. I *hope* not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the names are made up because I do not want to show real ones.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should use misleading names, @Nejc . Though an object's name is ***very*** unlikely to expose any meaningful information.

Comment: My point is why  replace function is in my case not working. If I run it like this: `select  '_#tmp_tt2_POS_racuni_'+((replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(),121),'-',''))+'-'+(replace(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),108),':','')))+'NP'`
it is ok.

Comment: The actual point is why create such a maintenance mess when you can handle data using the built-in features? If you can't even understand what that string formatting function does, you'll have far more serious problems going forward

Comment: Your `REPLACE` function is working, there's just nothing to replace. Style `121` returns a `varchar` in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`, and you want to replace the value `'-'` with `''`. There are no `'-'` patterns in your string. You *actually* should be replacing just `-` with a zero length string.

Comment: You can use `FORMAT` and specify the actual format you want, eg `select format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss')` or `select format(getdate(),'yyyyMMdd')`. It's slower than `CONVERT` but in this case you don't really care about performance.

Comment: Though, why not use style `112` (`yyyymmdd`); then you don't need to use the first 10 characters of style `121` (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`) and remove the hyphens (`-`).

Comment: @Larnu if you remove replace from my select you will get this format - > _#tmp_tt2_POS_racuni_2021-12-21-11:40:03NP

Comment: I know what your `REPLACE` is doing, @Nejc . Nothing; as there are no patterns to replace.

Comment: @Nejc what format *do* you want? It's easier to directly produce the format you want than struggle with replacements

Answer (score 3):

You should use `FORMAT` and specify the format you want directly instead of going through intermediate formats. For example :

```
select format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss')
```

Produces `20211221124017`. `FORMAT` is slower than CONVERT but in this case it's only called once. It's far more important to write a readable query that produces the correct result.

That said, it's probably better to use table partitioning instead of creating lots of temporary tables with a date in the name. All supported SQL Server versions and editions support partitioning, even LocalDB

Answer (score 2):

The quotes you use are two too many.

You are using `replace(date,''':''','''')`. This will replace `':'` with `''`. However, the getdate() doesn't have quotes itself. I guess you did that because of the dynamic sql you are using - but for the dates, you should omit the quotes:

`replace(date,':','')`

Comment: Yes this is solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's get onto the real problem that is discussed at lengths in the comments; this is a terrible idea.

The fact you want to create a table for an exact point in time smells *very* strongly of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). What is the real problem you are trying to solve with this? Most likely what you really want is a partitioned table or a temporal table, so that you can query the data for an exact point in time. Which you need, we don't know, but I would suggest that you rethink your "solution" here.

---

As for the problem, it's working exactly as intended. Let's look at your `REPLACE` in solitude:

```sql
replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(),121),'''-''','''')
```

So, in the above, you want to replace `'-'` (a hyphen wrapped in single quotes) with `''` (2 single quotes). You **don't** want to replace a hyphen (`-`) with a zero length string; that would be `REPLACE(..., '-','')`.

The style you are using, `121` gives the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`, which doesn't contain a single single quote (`'`), so no wonder it isn't finding the pattern.

Though you don't need `REPLACE` on that date at all. YOu are taking the first 10 characters or the style and then removing the hyphens (`-`) to get `yyyyMMdd`, but there is already a style for that; style `112`.

The above could be rewritten as:

```sql
DECLARE @Tabela sysname;
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
SET @Tabela = N'_#tmp_tt2_POS_racuni_';
SET @query = N'SELECT * INTO dbo.'+QUOTENAME(CONCAT(@Tabela,CONVERT(nvarchar(8),GETDATE(),112),,N'-'.REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),GETDATE(),108),':',''),N'',N'NP')+N' FROM dbo._tabels;'
PRINT @query;
```